# Absolute Dropdown inside a scrollable (x) parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-position

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-heyrovsky-l9bn4x?file=/src/dropdown.tsx

I want to display a dropdown inside a scrollable div in the x direction. The current problem is that when the dropdown expands so does the the scrollable in y direction. I want the dropdown select items to appear on top and not expand the parent div. The application is made with React.

```
<div className={`relative`}>
  <button>
    Menu
  </button>
  {dropdownMultipleExpand && (
    <div className={`absolute`}>
     ...
```

The dropdown is inside the following div:

```
<div className={"overflow-x-scroll"}>
</div>
```

https://l9bn4x.csb.app/

If I try to set the y direction scrollable to not show the absolute div will not be shown

Comment: I'm guessing you will probably need a solution similar to https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/